# SQL Server row level security on views

Tags: sql-server

Does the row-level security (RLS) feature of SQL Server work with views? That is, can I define something on the lines of

```sql
CREATE SECURITY POLICY rls.SecPol  
    ADD FILTER PREDICATE rls.tenantAccessPredicate(TenantId) ON dbo.view_Sales
```

Where `dbo.view_Sales` is not a SQL Server table but a view?

I suppose this is not possible, though I couldn't find any existing documentation about this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with the caveat that the view must be schemabound.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Tried it. It works. Either everything has to be schemabound or for everything schemabinding has t